# Linq count trouble

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, count, group-by

I have two tables:

```
tblBadge
-------
ID
Name

tblBadgeUsers
-------
BadgeID
UserID
```

A user can have many badges, all the relationships are set up properly in the SQL database.

I'm trying to return a list of all the badges a user has, along with the total number of those badges.  This is about as far as I can get, I'm getting pretty confused.  I want to return the tblBadge data along with an extra column showing the total of that badge awarded.

This doesn't work but is my attempt:

```
var q = db.tblBadgeUsers
    .Where(c => c.UserID == UserID)
    .GroupBy(c => c.BadgeID)
    .Select(c => new { BadgeCount = c.Count(), Record = c.tblBadge });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that a badge *only* really has a badge ID and a user, it sounds like you just need to get the badge ID and the count of that badge for the use - which means just getting the key for the group:

```
var q = db.tblBadgeUsers
    .Where(c => c.UserID == UserID)
    .GroupBy(c => c.BadgeID)
    .Select(c => new { BadgeCount = c.Count(), BadgeId = c.Key });
```

If there's more information on each badge, you might want to do:

```
var q = db.tblBadgeUsers
    .Where(c => c.UserID == UserID)
    .GroupBy(c => c.BadgeID)
    .Select(c => new { BadgeCount = c.Count(), BadgeId = c.Key, Badges = c });
```

Then you could do:

```
foreach (var badgeType in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", badgeType.BadgeId, badgeType.BadgeCount);
    foreach (var badge in q.Badges)
    {
        // Deal with the badge information
    }
}
```